# Ajax or post / get

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Как в 2019 году лучше реализовать работу сайта, на ajax или... стандартными методами браузера? Под фразой стандартные методы браузера я имею ввиду это:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="input1" class="testinput">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

А под фразой ajax я имею ввиду что-то вроде этого:

```
$.post("handler.php", { input1: $(".testinput").val() }, onAjaxSuccess);

function onAjaxSuccess(data){
   $("body").html(data);
}
```

В чем плюсы и минусы обоих способов и какой способ использовали бы вы?

Answer (score 0):

В 2019 году есть несколько методов "запустить" клиент сайта.

- HTML-based, вы не утруждаетесь работать с JS, в итоге браузер ведёт себя стандартно.
- Custom JS, зачастую вы пишете JS вручную, используя при этом небольшие обёртки, типа JQuery, при этом html зачастую генерируется на сервере.
- JS фреймворки, такие как Angular, React, Vue, вы используете их функционал (шаблоны, роутинг, тестирование, анимации, препроцессоры, typescript).

Другой вопрос, "Как в 2019 году лучше реализовать работу сайта **для пользователей**?"

Работая на сайте пользователи ожидают отзывчивости, как можно меньше прерываний и нужные элементы интерфейса в нужном месте.
В таком случае рациональнее будет использовать JS фреймворки для ускорения разработки и быстрого внесения изменений.